# Jquery Accordion UI control error

Tags: jquery, asp.net

hi i am trying to  learn and use a accordion control of Jquery UI with the below

**HTML CODE**

```
<div  id="accordionTest">           
    <div>
        <div id="dvError">
        </div>

        <div id="divbody">
        </div>   
    </div>
    <div id = "new">
    </div>
</div>
```

and

**JS CODE:**

```
$('#accordionTest').accordion();
```

but i am getting an error which says

> 'object doesn't support this property or method'

please help me in resolving this..

Comment: Is jQuery and jQueryUI included properly?

Comment: Yes, in the Master Page

Answer (score 1):

This error is because you have not included Jquery UI library or could not loaded correctly.

Add the below two library in your particular page to test.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Use firebug to verify.

See this [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9Pt3r/)

Comment: Thanks @Ashwini Verma. Yes i have included this in the Master page. But still getting error

Comment: See my update and add that library in that particular page and remove previous added lib from masterpage. That should work.

Comment: @CSharped You're saying it's on the Master page, but it's likely that you're having pathing issues, or you forgot to upload the library to the server, or something else like that. You should be able to figure this out by viewing the HTML source of the resulting page and using your browser's debug tools.